# Rails 4 - "Create" action in controller when it's a nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have a User model that has_many Photos (another model).  In the routes.rb file it's photos is a nested resource of user.  So, I have a form_for that uploads to the controller #create action.  I'm having trouble saving the photo into the database under the user.  How can I do this?  It says it saves correctly, because it redirects, but then it doesn't show that it has a photo (I also used the console to check not just my view).  What am I doing wrong?

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new(:user_id => params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    byebug
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:user_id])
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully added photo."
      redirect_to new_user_photo_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT----------

Adding in the form_for that gets us to the #create action.  Hope this helps :) I've been reading more about this, and I'm still not sure what to do to fix.

```
<%= form_for @photo, :url => user_photos_path(current_user.id, @photo), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Upload', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  &nbsp;or
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', users_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your form that is handling the upload as well? Typically, I will have something like @photo = current_user.photos.new so that someone doesn't mess around with parameters when passed back to the controller.

Comment: @kobaltz Yes, I posted the form_for

Comment: This line: `@photo = Photo.new(params[:user_id])` is raising alarms for me. Does it really make sense? I'd guess your want something more like `@photo = User.find(params[:user_id]).photos.new(photo_params)` where `photo_params` are the params from your form.

Comment: @ptd, add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @photo = Photo.new(:user_id => params[:user_id])
    @photos = @user.photos
  end

  def create
    @photo = User.find(params[:user_id]).photos.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully added photo."
      redirect_to new_user_photo_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  # GET /photos
  def index
    redirect_to new_user_photo_path
  end


  # GET /photos/1
  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @photos = Photo.all
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = User.find(params[:user_id]).photos.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted photo"
    redirect_to new_user_photo_path
  end

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit!
  end

end
```